# Textwrangler -- Trying to run a xmllint command

Tags: mac-osx, xml

When I run:

```
#!/bin/sh
xmllint --c14n "$*" | XMLLINT_INDENT=$'\t' xmllint --encode UTF-8 --format -
```

I get

> /private/var/folders/Aj/Aj9m3c8JGnmkccHY2o3lKE+++TI/Cleanup
>   At Startup/Tidy XML.sh.S:1: parser
>   error : Start tag expected, '<' not
>   found question_autoSwitch ^
>   -:1: parser error : Document is empty
>
> ^
>   -:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Something is very wrong. :P

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know anything, but that hat pipe `|` looks out of place.  did you mean to have another command after it or did you mean to escape it?

Comment: This is where I go the script http://magp.ie/2010/02/15/format-xml-with-textwrangler/

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
XMLLINT_INDENT=$'\t' xmllint --encode UTF-8 --format - $*
```